# The second angular custom element is not displayed

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element, angular-elements

I have two custom elements where I'm calling main.js.

[image]

I try to display both within another app using @angular-extensions/elements or just adding script to index.html. When I call the two custom elements I it just shows the first one on the screen, but when I look at the inspect it loads the main.js of the two elements.

Before calling the custom elements
[image]

After calling the custom elements, but it only shows the first custom element on the screen.
[image]

Custom element appears on screen
[image]

Does anybody know what happens?
As I said above, it loads the main.js of the two elements, but it only loads the first element.

Quando chamo os elementos customizados sem usar o ngIf, os dois aparecem, mas preciso utilizar a validacao do if.

code:
[image]

browser:
[image]